# efficiency of the closest pair algorithm

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

In T(n) = 2T(n/2) + M(n), where does the 2 in front of T come from.  n/2 because it is dividing, and M(n) is linear, but I can't figure out what the 2 is for?

Answer (score 4):

2, because you are performing the operation on the two subsets. See the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation is similar to what you get in [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_Sort). The time complexity would be [O(n log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Application_to_common_algorithms)

Comment: The 2 is because you are working on two subproblems of equal size i.e `n/2`

Answer (score 1):

This says that the time cost of the problem of size n comes from dividing the problem in half (i.e., T(n/2)) and solving it for both halves (2 T(n/2)) plus some fix-up cost (i.e., M(n)).

So, the 2 is because you divide the problem in half and solve both halves.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 represents how many times you're going to call the recurring function.

For example, if you had a tree that had 4 children, you would expect a 4 for that value. In this case, you're recurring twice.